# Register click event handler for extjs Grid in col model

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have one extjs grid

```
this.rentProofInfoGrid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
            store : this.rentProofInfoStore,
            id : 'rentProofInfoGrid',
            cm : this.rentProofColModel,
            autoWidth : true,
            height : 300,
            bodyBorder : true,
            clicksToEdit : 1,
            containerScroll : true,
            autoScroll : true,
            iconCls : 'icon-grid',
            tbar : [this.addRentProofAction, this.deleteRentProofAction],
            plugins : [this.attachmentButton, this.deleteAttachment,
                    this.downloadLink],
            sm : this.selModel
        });
```

where my colmodel is

```
this.rentProofColModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
        this.rentProofInfoMasterCombo, {
            id : 'landLordName',
            header : "Landlord Name",
            dataIndex : 'landLordName',
            width : 140,
            align : 'right',
            editor : new Ext.form.TextField({
                        id : 'landLordName',
                        emptyText : 'Name'
                    }),
            scope : this
        }, {
            id : 'landLordAdd',
            header : "Landlord Address",
            dataIndex : 'landLordAddr',
            width : 200,
            align : 'right',
            editor : new Ext.form.TextField({
                        id : 'landLordAdd',
                        emptyText : 'Address'
                    }),
            scope : this
        }, {
            id : 'landLordPan',
            header : "Landlord PAN",
            dataIndex : 'landLordPAN',
            width : 100,
            align : 'right',
            editor : new Ext.form.TextField({
                        id : 'landLordPan',
                        emptyText : 'PAN Number'
                    }),
            scope : this
        }, {
            id : 'viewDeclaration',
            header : "View Declaration",
            dataIndex : 'viewDeclaration',
            width : 100,
            align : 'right',
            renderer : function(val, p, record) {
                var link = '';
                if (val != null) {
                    link = "<span class='downloadLink' row_id='"
                            + record.data.id
                            + "' style='text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;'>"
                            + val + "<span>";
                }
                return link;
            }
        }, this.attachmentButton, this.deleteAttachment]);
```

in my one column "viewDeclaration" i am creating a renderer to make dataIndex value as hyperlink now my problem is how do i register a click event on click of that span can any one plz help me?

Comment: Which version of Ext JS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Ext.select to retrieve a list of node matching a CSS selector.

```
Ext.select('. downloadLink').on('click', function() { alert('bar'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would handle the `cellclick` event on the grid. 
the doc (ExtJS 2.2) says:

```
cellclick : ( Grid this, Number rowIndex, Number columnIndex, Ext.EventObject e )
```

handle this event with a function such as this:

```
function(grid, rowIndex, columnIndex, e) {
    var record = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);  // Get the Record
    var fieldName = grid.getColumnModel().getDataIndex(columnIndex); // Get field name
    var data = record.get(fieldName);
}
```

Also in this function you can get exactly what the user clicked on by doing:

```
e.getTarget('.downloadLink') //returns you an HTMLElement
```

Once you have the HTML element you can pretty much do whatever type of checking you want to do with it. You can even check if it has the "row_id" property that you specified in the renderer.